# Joomla! custom component css issue

Tags: html, css, joomla, components

Building a custom Joomla! component, in my Admin interface a css class with value m (`<div class="m"> </div>`)is getting called every time. How could ignore to not get included. I'm searching in the source but till now without any result.

Comment: Check inside the views folder for the class that is added. Unless the class is being added via javascript. Either way, I didn't understand what you mean by "is getting every time called"...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't found where, I can propose interesting method.

You may delete the class `m` with jQuery method.

On page load get element with class `m` and delete this class from that element.

```
<script>
    (function(){
        $('.m').removeClass('m');
    })
</script>
```

Comment: the idea is not bad, but is not the cleanest

Answer (score 1):

It's done by the bluestork template and is responsible to built the light grey box with rounded corners around the submenu, your extension output and such things.
If you don't like it, change it in the template or use a different template :-)

But then, what is your issue with it? Does it break something?